# i cant send data from a textarea using AJAX (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

i have a problem;
I cant send data from a textarea using AJAX WITH PHP and MYSQLI

anyway; the code for admin.php:

```
<?php include("head.php");
include("../includes/frame.php");
$get = $_GET['get'];
if ($get == "update") {
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
update_notes($notes);
} else {
 ?>
<body>

<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>للوحة التحكم</h1>
        <p>أكتب ما شئت هخ</p>


        <div id="box">
            <div class="box-top" align="center">ملاحظات المدير العام</div>
            <div class="box-panel" align="center">
            <form>
            <textarea id="adminnotes" name="notes" dir="rtl" rows="10"><?php echo      show_notes(); ?></textarea><br>   
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="تحديث" id="submit">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```

And the code of script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var adminnotes = $("#adminnotes").val();

var dataString = '&notes='+ adminnotes;
if(adminnotes=='')
{
alert("المرجو ملأ البيانات");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "admin.php?get=update",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(){
alert("تم تحديث البيانات بنجاح");
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

i think that the problem is from the line 16 in the file script.js:

THANKYOU VERY MUCH

Comment: can you please correctly format your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html

```
<form>
```

use

```
<form method="get" action="#" id="update_notes">
```

in script.js 
use

```
$("#update_notes").on('submit',function(){
```

instead of

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

and 
change

```
type: "POST",
```

to

```
type:"GET",
```

in admin.php

```
<?php include("head.php");
include("../includes/frame.php");
$get = $_GET['get']; // this data from the link
$dataString = $_GET['dataString']; // this data from ajax
if ($get == "update") {
update_notes($dataString);
} else {
 ?>
<body>

<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>للوحة التحكم</h1>
        <p>أكتب ما شئت هخ</p>


        <div id="box">
            <div class="box-top" align="center">ملاحظات المدير العام</div>
            <div class="box-panel" align="center">
            <form>
            <textarea id="adminnotes" name="notes" dir="rtl" rows="10"><?php echo      show_notes(); ?></textarea><br>   
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="تحديث" id="submit">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```